# What is Facebook's new OAuth Wrap Framework? Should I worry about it if I am using OAuth?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I have just implemented OAuth as a signup mechanism complementing the standard signup we have.

Recently, Facebook seems to have started using OAuth WRAP.
What is new in OAuth WRAP? What are the pros and cons and is it supported widely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary difference is that it replaces the key/token sharing on the server<->server communication with an ssl channel, which is known to be good, and doesn't need additional protection from impersonators. This in turn makes it simpler to implement as a consumer (and a producer).

It looks like there is a [white-paper](http://groups.google.com/group/oauth-wrap-wg/files) on the OAuth WRAP WG site.